# martingale/ harmonic function practice question

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let {$S_n$} be a modified random walk on the positive integers,  where $P(S_n=k+1|F_n)$ is no longer $\frac{1}{2}$ but instead is $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4k}$  Use the harmonic function $f(n) = n^2$ to compute the probability that the walk, if started from 50 and absorbed when it hits 0, will ever reach 100.

I'm very confused about this problem. I mostly want a solution and explanation to the problem itself.

However, if it's not too much trouble, I would also like to know why this question discusses $P(S_n=k+1|F_n)$ and not $P(S_n=k+1|F_{n-1})$? Isn't {$S_n$} adapted to {$F_n$}, which would make $P(S_n=k+1|F_n)$  = $E(1_{S_n=k+1}|F_n) = 1_{S_n=k+1}$? What am I missing?

Also, what exactly is k?

Comment: Yeah, I agree about it being probably $P(S_n=k+1|F_{n-1}=\ldots$. But it seems the condition would be better phrased by $P(S_{n+1}-S_n=1|F_n)=1(S_n > 0)(0.5-\frac{1}{S_n})$.

Comment: I think it means that, if the random walk is currently at a height of $k$, it goes up at the next step with probability $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4k}$ and goes down at the next step with probability $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4k}$.

Comment: $f(n)$ is not harmonic. It's second derivative with respect to $n$ is not zero.

Comment: I think the author is referring to a discrete harmonic function with some discrete laplacian $\Delta f(n)= c f(n+1)+df(n-1)-f(n)$ for some appropriate constants $c$ and $d$. Basically, the statement should be that $f(S_n)$ is a martingale, and then you can apply Optional Sampling to solve the exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay: So writing it up cleanly. We claim that $f(S_n)$ is a martingale.
Note that
$$
\mathbb{E}(f(S_{n+1})-f(S_n)|F_n)=1_{(S_n>0)}\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4 S_n}\right)\left(1+2 S_n\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4 S_n}\right)\left(1-2 S_n\right)\right)=0
$$
Then, if $\tau$ is the first hitting time of $\{0,100\}$, we see that $f(S_{n\wedge \tau})$ is a uniformly bounded martingale by optional sampling. Applying dominated convergence, we get

$$
10^4\mathbb{P}(S_{\tau}=100)=\mathbb{E}(f(S_{\tau}))=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}(f(S_{n\wedge \tau}))=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}(f(S_0))=10^2 \cdot5^2
$$

This implies that 
$$
\mathbb{P}(S_{\tau}=100)=\frac{1}{4}
$$
Which gives you your solution.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the second and third lines, but not all of the first line. In particular, if $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4k}$ is the probability of going up and $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4k}$ is the probability of going down, then why are they multiplied by the same thing, and why is that thing $(1 + 2S_n)$? Also, you seem to be saying that $k = \frac{S_n}{2}$. Why is that? Lastly, I don't understand what you're using the expected value term for.

Comment: I apologise. There were, indeed, a bunch of typos. When $S_n$ increases, we get $f(S_{n+1})-f(S_n)=(S_{n}+1)^2-S_n^2=1+2S_n$ and when $S_n$ decreases, we get $f(S_{n+1})-f(S_n)=(S_n-1)^2-S_n^2=1-2S_n$.

Comment: I'm using the expected value term to apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem and the martingale property of $f(S_{n\wedge \tau})$.